# Is the given space is a banach algebra and find it’s maximal ideal space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $ \mathcal{A} =\left\{f \in C(\mathbb{T}): \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}, \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f\left(e^{i \theta}\right) e^{i n \theta} \mathrm{d} \theta=0\right\}$.prove $ \mathcal{A}$ is a banach algebra and find its maximal ideal space

I have aleady prove $ \mathcal{A}$ is a banach algebra,but I don’t know how to find its maximal ideal space ,hope you can give me some methods to fix it

Comment: Is it the $L^\infty$ norm?

Comment: Clearly $\mathbb{T}\subset \operatorname{max}(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: yes from my perspective it's L∞norm. can you add more detais about your comment because i'm not good at functional analais realy

Comment: Do you know $\operatorname{max}(C(X))$ for a compact Hausdorff space $X$?